# Seemingly equivalent queries in LINQ and SQL returns different results

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, linq, join

*Not sure why it got linked as a dupe. The question is way different. The answer is different. Not sure what to change. If someone sees what I'm missing, please let me know...*

I'm getting different number of results using those two queries. After having analyzed it for a few hours I need to throw in the towel, admitting that I can't spot the difference of significance. Since my arsenal of approaches is emptied, I'm asking for help.

LINQ

```
List<Uno> result = context.Unos
  .Join(context.Duos, uno => uno.CommonId, duo => duo.CommonId,
    (uno, duo) => new { Uno = uno, Duo = duo })
  .Where(item => item.Uno.Amount > 0
    && item.Duo.Type == 2)
  .Select(item => item.Uno)
  .ToList();
```

SQL

```
select * from Uno as u
join Duo as d on d.CommonId = u.CommonId
where u.Amount > 0
  and d.Type = 2
```

Question number one is if the above two statements are indeed equivalent or if I'm missing something. Question number two is what I'm missing (if anything) or how to trouble-shoot it (if I'm not).

1. Calls are made against the same database.
2. The numbers of results are vastly apart (142 and 1437).
3. The same result sets are fetched for inner join.
4. Both *Uno* and *Duo* are views, not tables.

What more can I verified?

## Edit

After some awesomely great support from the community, we established that the LINQ query can be SQL'ized by the following command.

```
var wtd = context.Unos
  .Join(context.Duos, uno => uno.CommonId, duo => duo.CommonId,
    (uno, duo) => new { Uno = uno, Duo = duo })
  .Where(item => item.Uno.Amount > 0
    && item.Duo.Type == 2)
  .Select(item => item.Uno)
  .ToString();
```

The crazy thing is that executing **that** string in SQL Manager produces 142 results (just as the query in the example above, the SQL version) and it differs only insignificantly from it. However, executing the LINQ query itself produces 1437 results. I'm too confused to even start crying...

> "SELECT \r\n    [Extent1].[CommonId] AS [CommonId], \r\n    [Extent1].[X] AS [X]\r\n    FROM  (SELECT \n    [Uno].[CommonId] AS [CommonId], \n    [Uno].[X] AS [X]\n    FROM [Finance].[Uno] AS [Uno]) AS [Extent1]\r\n    INNER JOIN (SELECT \n    [Duo].[CommonId] AS [CommonId], \n    [Duo].[Y] AS [Y], \n    [Duo].[Z] AS [Z], \n    [Duo].[Type] AS [Type], \n    [Duo].[U] AS [U], \n    [Duo].[V] AS [V]\n    FROM [Finance].[Duo] AS [Duo]) AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[CommonId] = [Extent2].[CommonId]\r\n    WHERE ([Extent1].[X] > cast(0 as decimal(18))) AND ([Extent2].[Type] = @p__linq__0)"

Comment: 'and d.Type = 2' a typo? What are the rowcounts of he two sources? which result, if any is the right one?

Comment: @TaW A typo? Not as far I can see. Do I miss something? The type is an integer which is always 2 (for this operation). It's in the table *Duo*.

Comment: @TaW Row counts are 142 and 1437 respectively (see #2). I'm not sure which is the correct one but I'd guess the SQL version. The one giving the lower number of results. Also, it's not tables but views, if that's of any importance.

Comment: show sql-code generated with LINQ

Comment: @Backs Not sure how. When I break-point and hover over the query I only get to see a *SELECT* without join and such. How do I obtain the actual query being executed?

Comment: some sql-profiler (MSSQL or others)

Comment: @Backs Mmmkey... Still not sure what to do. Are you referring to Sql Server? Or is it a tool that I'm familiar with? Are we talking about VS and plugins to it?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173799(v=sql.120).aspx look here

Comment: No, I missed the SQL header, sorry. I meant the number of rows in the source tables/views.

Comment: @TaW No problem. Do you see anything obvious that I might be missing? I'll check the suggestion to install some profiler that Backs gave me a link to maybe that'll shed some light...

Comment: @Backs No luck. Apparently I have some por-man's version installed. I can't find the tools (I've followed all the how-to-start suggestions) so I'm guessing they're not available on my system. Suggestions?

Comment: [Display LINQ to SQL Commands](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882652%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: @lad2025 Awesome. I only get stuck on the part of getting the database reference. I have a context via EF so I couldn't get the command out of it, nor from the result set. Suggestion on where to get it (related to the code in my examples)?

Comment: Try to take a look on query that you run after LINQ execution in IntelliTrace window while you debugging this place. And then compare to your SQL, I think they are different.

Comment: Check https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.objectquery.totracestring.aspx

Comment: @Chase I'm **sure** they're different. I just can't see why/where, hehe. Also, IntelliTrace is a no-go. VS13 Pro, only. I know, I know - I deserve to be spoiled with some better tools. :)

Comment: okay, not a problem also, take this:https://expressprofiler.codeplex.com/
very simple and useful.

Comment: @lad2025 No go again, sadly. I get it to work with *Where()* but it nags on my *Join()*. And it's the joining that creates the problem. Keep the suggestions coming. They're awesome.

Comment: trying to understand here, the `ToList()`, won't it return `List<<anonymous type: Unos, Duos>>` instead of `List<Unos>`. Isn't this a compile time error. your linq query must be working thats why you got the result `142`. How did it went past this compile time error?

Comment: @singsuyash Good eyes. I skipped the *Select* part to make the example shorter. I'll correct the typo right away. It's still the same, weird issue, though. Do you see anything else too?

Comment: You can intercept sql installing `sp_whoisactive` on server side http://sqlblog.com/files/folders/beta/entry42453.aspx. When your procedure is on server just `EXEC sp_whoisactive` and you get all running queries. Probably you will get some parametrized sp_executesql query generated by EF.

Comment: @KonradViltersten Have you tried this `var query = .....` everything except `ToList`. then `var sql = query.ToString();` and open with Text Visualizer

Comment: @IvanStoev I haven't before but now I have. And here's the insane part. When I execute the LINQ query I get 1437 results **but** when I execute the SQL from it (as per your hint) i get 142. Now, can someone tell me, pretty, pretty, please, what the duck (typo intended) is this all about?! Also, you want to post your comment as an answer because it definitely deserves some +1'ing and pushed the issue to its edge.

Comment: @KonradViltersten You welcome mate, glad that helped a bit. Really weird issue, never heard something like this. Hope you will post your own answer when you resolve it. Good luck!

Comment: @KonradViltersten Show that query that `differs only insignificantly from it.`

Comment: Hm, ToString(), really??? Did you look into the big result set and check if it contains null postions? These __might__ lead to those items being left out from __both__ the SQL as per definition of left inner join __and__ out of the string  as well..

Comment: @lad2025 Please see the edit in the question. I'm posting a part of it as an example. However, I can lower your expectations as the only differences is that it's capitalized keywords and *[Extent1]* there. Also, please remember that the ToString'ed SQL produces produces the same result set as the explicit SQL query so the logical difference is zero.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that one of the tables has not been mapped with a genuinely unique primary key in EF.

Comment: @GertArnold You're kind of a genius. And you definitely want to post that as a reply, not a comment. As I've investigated the issue deeper, I discovered that the primary key of the view is somehow faked up with some SQL saying "IFNULL" or something like that. Still, kind of weird that the LINQ and the SQL from that LINQ give different results.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is something that often happens when views are mapped in Entity Framework. Unlike regular database tables, views often don't have clearly unique key values. When EF encounters rows with identical primary key values, it just duplicates the row that belongs to the key it already knows. In joins, this may cause EF to produce more child records because this first-known row may have more children than the real database row.

The fix is to make sure that the view has a field (or combination of fields) that uniquely identifies a row. And, of course, in EF this should be mapped as a (possibly composite) primary key.

I don't know why EF displays this behavior. I think it should be possible for it to throw an exception that it materializes duplicate entities. This "feature" always causes a lot of confusion.

Answer (score 1):

Try to take a look on query that you run after LINQ execution in IntelliTrace window while you debugging this place. And then compare to your SQL, I think they are different. If you don't have IntelliTrace, try [Express Profiler](https://expressprofiler.codeplex.com/). Just set name of SQL Server, click Trace and spy it. I hope it will help!

Comment: Sigh... Guess who's got no permissions to perform tracing... I'll try to grant me one on the server but probably I can't. +1 for great effort anyway and I'll get back to you if I managed to get the permission.

Comment: Of course, executing *grant alter trace to NServiceBus*, which I'm using to login, produced an error saying that I can't. It seems that I already have those... What exactly do I enter in the server text box in the profiler? I put in 10.100.128.35, which is the IP to the server but perhaps I need to enter something more?

Comment: Okay, I thought you are developing on local environment. Next variant, call ToTraceString() instead of ToList() and change return value to var. Debug it, and in result variable you will have text of query.

Comment: I have no *ToTraceString()* according to the intellisense. I tried putting it right there *ToList* is now. No luck...

Comment: I got a hint from someone and got the SQL executed by the query. Really weird - check out the latest comments on the original post.

Answer (score 1):

This is a long shot but would this LINQ expression change anything?

```
(from uno in context.Unos
 join duo in context.Duos on uno.CommonId equals duo.CommonId
 where uno.Amount > 0 && duo.Type == 2
 select new {Uno = uno, Duo = duo}
).ToList()
```

I like this form better because it looks like the real SQL request. Somehow, the Join statement in your LINQ bothers me...

Comment: Same result as in the bothering LINQ. However, I'll grant you +1 because you just pushed the issue further. We now know that the expression above (the SQLish form) still produces a higher number of results than its SQL counterpart.

Comment: Thank you :) This issue reminds me of the first time I used SQL and the Join keyword which resulted in a long list of duplicated rows... Maybe a Distinct might help!

Comment: Nope, no go. I tried making the result set distinct - same counts returned. Darn it's so frustrating not to be able to pinpoint such things... I've talked to my boss and we'll just execute the SQL query as a string but, although pragmatically sufficient, it's not a nice solution at all. Feels like giving in to the stupid, crappy computer, hehe.

Comment: Actually it will probably be the bettter solution, as it will let the DBMS do its job and minimze the network traffic. But I understand your frustration. Maybe if you mumble 'jonskeetjonskeetjonskeet'..?