# Linq group by grouping wrong set of results

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-6

Fellow developers,

I've never had an issue not nearly as close to this one and haven't found any answers throughout the interwebs...

I have a simple query:

```
var data = (from b in db.vw_SpedF500
                    where b.DATABAIXA >= dtInicial && b.DATABAIXA <= dtFinal
                    where b.CODCOLIGADA == codcoligada
                    select b).ToList();
```

For the case i'm using, the view returns exactely 441 results.
I need to group them by the column named CSTPIS, which can have three different values (string): 01, 06 or 08.

The result count I'm expecting is:

- 01 => 170 results;
- 06 => 143 results;
- 08 => 128 results;

The result count after grouping:

- 01 => 170 results;
- 06 => 172 results;
- 08 => 109 results;

This is my group by query:

```
b.LinhasF500 = (from d in grupo
                                group d by d.CSTPIS into g
                                select new F500()
                                {
                                    VL_REC_CAIXA = g.Sum(f => f.VALOR.Value).ToString("F2"),

                                    CST_COFINS = g.FirstOrDefault().CSTCOFINS,
                                    VL_BC_COFINS = g.FirstOrDefault().CSTCOFINS == "08" ? null : g.Sum(f => f.VALOR.Value).ToString("F2"),
                                    ALIQ_COFINS = g.FirstOrDefault().CSTCOFINS == "08" ? null : g.FirstOrDefault().ALIQUOTACOFINS.Value.ToString("F2"),
                                    VL_COFINS = g.FirstOrDefault().CSTCOFINS == "08" ? null : g.Sum(f => f.COFINSBAIXA.Value).ToString("F2"),

                                    CST_PIS = g.FirstOrDefault().CSTPIS,
                                    ALIQ_PIS = g.FirstOrDefault().CSTPIS == "08" ? null : g.FirstOrDefault().ALIQUOTAPIS.Value.ToString("F2"),
                                    VL_PIS = g.FirstOrDefault().CSTPIS == "08" ? null : g.Sum(f => f.PISBAIXA.Value).ToString("F2"),
                                    VL_BC_PIS = g.FirstOrDefault().CSTPIS == "08" ? null : g.Sum(f => f.VALOR.Value).ToString("F2")
                                }).ToList();
```

Why on earth would Linq duplicate 10 results?

PS: Group by directly on sql query works correctly

**EDIT**

After checking Ivan's comment, I noticed the following:

EF identified a composite key for my view using three columns: IDLAN, CODCFO and CODCOLIGADA.

After running this query

```
select IDLAN, CODCFO, CODCOLIGADA, COUNT(IDLAN), COUNT(CODCFO), COUNT(CODCOLIGADA) from vw_SpedF500
where 0=0
    AND DATABAIXA BETWEEN '2015-08-01' AND '2015-08-31'
    and CODCOLIGADA = 7
GROUP BY IDLAN, CODCFO, CODCOLIGADA
HAVING COUNT(IDLAN) > 1 AND COUNT(CODCFO) > 1 AND COUNT(CODCOLIGADA) > 1
ORDER BY IDLAN
```

I get 124 rows where all three keys have more than one register.

Is there any way I can make this work on EF?

**EDIT**

I have re-checked everything again. The first query returns the correct results and the objects are already in memory.

The problem occurs when grouping the objects that are already in memory, and not during the query. It has nothing to do with EF.

I think I'll change this to an SqlCommand (will cause a small performance problem, since I'll have to run this query three times, but...)

Comment: Is `vw_SpedF500` a database **table** or **view**? If it is a view (as it seems by the name), take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33583309/seemingly-equivalent-queries-in-linq-and-sql-returns-different-results - the answer by Gert Arnold

Comment: Suggested simplification: Instead of `g.FirstOrDefault().CSTPIS`, use `g.Key` since that is the key and it should be the same for every record in the group and be marginally less costly.

Comment: The latter query uses `grupo` as its starting point instead of `data` created by the first query. Perhaps something has been changed in grupo from where it started in data?

Comment: @KaseySpeakman The second query is just incapsulated inside a method. Grupo is exactely the same thing as data (I've triple checked it). I liked your tip about using the group Key. Hadn't thought ouf that.

Comment: @IvanStoev After running some tests I've noticed I do get caught on the problem stated by Gert Arnold's answer. Will update question.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your LINQ query might be too restrictive - this has caught me out a few times. Use a less restrictive filter by removing your second `where` keyword and combining the final statement with your first.

Something like this should give you what you want:

```
var data = (from b in db.vw_SpedF500
            where b.DATABAIXA >= dtInicial &&
                  b.DATABAIXA <= dtFinal &&
                  b.CODCOLIGADA == codcoligada
            select b).ToList();
```

If you're trying to ensure that your LINQ query only returns results that match this:

```
b.DATABAIXA >= dtInicial && b.DATABAIXA <= dtFinal
```

**OR** this (as opposed to **and** this)

```
b.CODCOLIGADA == codcoligada
```

You could try this:

```
var data = (from b in db.vw_SpedF500
            where (b.DATABAIXA >= dtInicial &&
                   b.DATABAIXA <= dtFinal) ||
                   b.CODCOLIGADA == codcoligada
            select b).ToList();
```

I hope I've understood this right!

Comment: The first query is working correctly, as I've stated. Using multiple where clauses is the same as using multiple && for linq to entities as it returns the same sql query. My problem is related to grouping the results after the query. =)