# Entity Framework maps data wrong when the identity column is not unique

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Without getting into the "why", just understand this in inherited and what I have to work with :)

I have an EF6 edmx mapped to a view. There is no identifying column on it, so in order for EF to map the entity, the first not-null column was selected as the PK. The original thought behind this was it is *read only* no updates or deletes would be done. There is no filtering (ODATA sits on top of this), and the *only* - and I mean only - way this is used is `select top N *` from the entity.

There are 4 records in the view.

```
TypeCode | Contact | UserID | LocaleID | EntityName
---------------------------------------------------------
1          6623      1032     9          Jane
1          6623      1032     9          Jane
1          6623      1032     9          John
1          6623      1032     9          John
```

The problem I am seeing is that EF is mapping all 4 rows the same. All "John" names above become "Jane"

OK, putting aside the design decision, and the fact there is no identifying record on the view, why is EF mapping the last two rows wrong? My initial thought is that since the "PK" is set as `TypeCode` It doesn't know how to do it. But why would it be using the key column when just reading results from the database? I would have thought it only mattered for updates and deletes

Comment: Joe, does it matter why, it is known to be working this way and you have to live with that.

Comment: @IvanStoev Is it known? Does it actually use the column defined as the Key in selects?

Comment: Well, looks like. Don't have a documentation or explanation link, I learned it from this thread [Seemingly equivalent queries in LINQ and SQL returns different results](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33583309/seemingly-equivalent-queries-in-linq-and-sql-returns-different-results), but then found similar in many other places.

Comment: Have you looked at what SQL Profiler spits out? What queries are happening behind the scenes? Additionally, would making all the columns together a primary key solve it?

Comment: I have the sql generated returns data correct to EF. EF itself is doing something weird. I can't make the other columns part of the key because they can be null.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you query data by Entity Framework, the default behavior is that each materialized entity is tracked by its unique key. The unique key consists of any properties you told EF to use as key, or, alternatively, it inferred as key properties (`TypeCode` in your case). Whenever a duplicate entity key tries to enter the change tracker, an error is thrown telling that the object is already being tracked.

So EF simply *can't* materialize objects having duplicate primary key values. It would compromise its tracking mechanism.

It appears that, at least in EF6, [`AsNoTracking()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.infrastructure.dbquery.asnotracking(v=vs.113).aspx) can be used as a work-around. `AsNoTracking` tells EF to just materialize objects without tracking them, so it doesn't generate entity keys.

What I *don't* understand is why EF doesn't throw an exception whenever it reads duplicate primary key values. Now it silently returns the same object as many times as it encounters its key value in the SQL query result. This has caused many many people to get confused to no end.

By the way, a common way to avoid this issue is by generating temporary unique key values to the view by using [`ROW_NUMBER`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) in Sql Server. That's good enough for read-only data that you read once into one context instance.

Comment: My question above is a very simplified version of what is going one. The crazy thing is that it is those 4 rows. There are 14K records in the table, all with the same TypeCode value, and those do not exhibit the same behavior. The only thing I can think is those 4 records share data across the other 3 columns. I think EF may be doing more than a "simple" Identity map pattern when materializing the records. Either way, I will try to use `AsNoTracking` and see what's up

Comment: Just curious, do you know where in the EF code this is done? I'm hunting around their Github, but to no avail

Comment: I dig through EF code quite often, but I'd be a savant if I knew this off the top of my head. But what would you gain by knowing that? It would be virtually impossible to modify this behavior (if you even would) because it's at the root of EF's tracking mechanism.

Comment: Because I would like to step through it and see exactly what is going on. Learning for learning's sake?

Comment: As for the 4 rows. Are you sure EF only infers `TypeCode` as primary key? Your description of the behavior makes me think it also takes the other three.

Comment: As part of the code generation, we modified the .tt file to do that, and looking at the .cs file for the view only TypeCode has the [key] attribute on it. Unless there is another place to set the key..

Comment: That's interesting. And I can confirm this. I can't remember having seen this as fix (or work-around) before. Maybe it's a relatively recent change in EF.

Comment: Any idea if there is a global place to set AsNoTracking?

Comment: No, there isn't, you have to tack it to each individual `DbSet`. Of course your `DbContext` could have a property that encapsulates it for the view.

Comment: I had a similar problem and discovered that I was missing one [Key] attribute out of 3 composite Keys.  Once I added the [Key, Column("ColumnName", Order = 2)] attribute to my entity model the mapping worked correctly.