# LINQ returns wrong value for one specific column in SQL View query

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, linq, view

My issue seems to be simple, but I can't figure out what's happening.

I have the following LINQ query:

```
(from p in db.VW_PROJETOS
  join ic in db.vw_InstanciaCarteira
  on p.CodigoProjeto equals ic.CodigoProjeto
  where ic.CodigoCarteira == 125
  orderby p.CodigoProjeto
  select p).ToList();
```

It returns 9 entries from VW_PROJETOS, such as IDs, FKs, string, dates... If I execute same query in SQL Server Management Studio, as the following

```
select * from VW_PROJETOS p 
inner join vw_InstanciaCarteira ic on p.CodigoProjeto = ic.CodigoProjeto
where ic.CodigoCarteira = 125 
order by p.CodigoProjeto
```

it will return the same 9 entries, with the same data for each entry, except for column "Desempenho". Here's a short example:

SQL Server returns:

```
CodigoProjeto NomeProjeto Desempenho
13            Projeto 1   Satisfatório
1247          Projeto 2   NULL
1435          Projeto 3   Crítico
```

LINQ query returns:

```
CodigoProjeto NomeProjeto Desempenho
13            Projeto 1   Crítico   
1247          Projeto 2   Crítico   
1435          Projeto 3   Satisfatório
```

I saw some examples of using `ROW_NUMBER` to create indexes for the views, in order to help LINQ to not loses itself when working with views, but I couldn't make it work right (the index that was shown in SQL query was always different from the index that LINQ returns).

Is this a common issue? Is it easy to correct or workaround? It can be an error in the View itself?

**EDIT:**

Following some of your advices, I checked the relation between unique keys and fields in Entity Framework entities. I put several keys, properly ordered, in both EF entities, but the result was the same. I got the SQL query generated by my LINQ and it gives exactly the same result as the one I posted above. I've also generated the models again, using Code-First from Database, in order to have keys ordered by the code generation, and it was useless as well.

Comment: `VW_PROJETOS` is a database view, right? This is a known EF issue with views that has no PK defined.

Comment: @ivan-stoev yes, it is a view. What's the best way to define a PK in a View? I've never done it before.

Comment: @ivan-stoev BTW, is it really a PK? I'm searching about it and it seems that views can't have PKs, only indexes.

Comment: Check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33583309/seemingly-equivalent-queries-in-linq-and-sql-returns-different-results/33615293#33615293) for a similar issue. This where I've heard for the problem for the first time. I'm not so familiar, but I think you should define PK for the EF entity (it doesn't need to be real db PK, just unique field or combination of fields).

Comment: @ivan-stoev I put several keys, properly ordered, in both EF entities, but the result is the same. I got the SQL query generated by my LINQ and it's exactly the same result as the one I posted above. I've also generated the models again, using Code-First from Database, in order to have keys ordered by the code generation, and it was useless as well.

Answer (score 1):

```
Use this query.

(from p in db.VW_PROJETOS
  join ic in db.vw_InstanciaCarteira
  on p.CodigoProjeto equals ic.CodigoProjeto
  where ic.CodigoCarteira == 125
  orderby p.CodigoProjeto
  select  new {
  CodigoProjeto=p.CodigoProjeto,
  NomeProjeto=p. NomeProjeto,
  Desempenho=ic.Desempenho
  }.ToList();
```

Comment: "Desempenho" is from VW_PROJETOS, not vw_InstanciaCarteira. Moreover, your query is no different than mine (I'm using anonymous object as well, but removed it from the example above because it would be too big).

Answer (score 0):

Check the data type for the column "CodigoProjeto" in both db.vw_InstanciaCarteira and db.VW_PROJETOS. They should match.

Comment: Also, trim the values before matching, you might have some extra space in some of the values.

Comment: It would be better if you edit your question instead giving a comment.

Comment: The column is INT in both SQL and LINQ references for both views.